# jQuery UI with Ruby on Rails - 304 Not Modified Processing Message - Slow Loading Time of Web Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2

## The Problem:

The adding of `jQuery UI 1.9` to `Ruby on Rails 3.2` has caused a ***slow loading time*** of the web page.

## The Processing Message:

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/i18n/
jquery.ui.datepicker-tj.min.js?body=1" for *[localhost]*
Served asset /jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom/development-bundle/ui/minified/i18n/jquery.
ui.datepicker-tj.min.js - 304 Not Modified (15ms)
```

## The Question:

This processing message does re-occur repeatedly. How, and also where can the processing message `304 Not Modified` be set?

Comment: It's not a warning. 304 not modified is the response code for when it didn't have to recompile anything because there have been no changes since the last request to that asset. It does this with the asset pipeline. Jquery ui is a heavy-ish library. If you're using the development bundle rather than production assets, it could be slow because of that. You generally just need the 2 javascript files, css and images. 1 js file is for jquery ui, the other is for jquery itself (which you can remove if you are already loading jquery).

Comment: The question has been edited. I have also downloaded jQuery UI again without the widgets, yet the processing message still does occur, and the loading time of the web pages are still slow, nevertheless.

Comment: It wasnt so much about not packaging the widgets, but you shouldnt have to make requests to the files in the development-bundle. Delete that folder from your asset pipeline. If you look at the packaged index.html file, it only includes the css file and the two files in the js directory. The development-bundle directory is around 6mb in size. That's pretty big for the web to load, and not to mention for rails to try and figure out.